# Should I be calling Dispose on Reactive Extensions (Rx) Subject<T>

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am using the Reactive Extensions (Rx) Subject as a direct replacement for C# events like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Subject<string> subject;

    public IObservable<string> WhenSomethingHappened
    {
        get { return this.subject.AsObservable(); }
    }

    private void OnSomethingHappened(string something)
    {
        this.subject.OnNext(something);
    }
}
```

Note that I never call OnCompleted on my subject. Should MyClass be implementing IDisposable and calling this.subject.Dispose? This would mean that any implementation using Subject should implement IDisposable.

The reason I ask is that the IDisposable pattern is a bit like a disease, if one thing implements it, everything that uses it has to implement it too.

Comment: MyClass and subject will "live" during the whole application life cycle? Do you want to unsubscribe observers from it?

Comment: Yes it does in my case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nope, you don't really need to do this. When worrying about memory usage and lifetimes, think about disposing *Subscriptions*, not Subjects.

Comment: If you look at the source code for Subject (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Subjects/Subject.cs) you can see all it does it replace any observers with a DisposedObserver instance. This will then throw if the subject has any event thrown to it. So technically I think it would release references to all observers, but that should really be done by disposing of your subscriptions as Paul says above

Comment: Good answer and comment. Have an up-vote each. What if you're implementing IDisposable anyway? There seem to be a lot of objects which implement IDisposable but it's recommended that they are never disposed. The new HttpClient is another example.

Comment: @LeeCampbell the link is broken

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed Task is another example

Comment: @Yitzchak I have googled for the current link to the Subject source code and here is the link https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/Subject.cs#L279
The comment above was from over 5 years ago

Comment: If this is true, then why do Subjects implement the IDisposable contract?