# How do I set an Observable to watch a Property?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I realize this is probably a very stupid question but the documentation on Reactive Extensions is both opaque and scattered.

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooState {get;set;}
}
```

and FooState is updated very frequently.  This looks like an ideal case for an IObservable, especially since I'll have to track that state in another class.

```
public class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo {get;set;}

    private void DoStuffWithFooState()
    {
        //operate on Foo.FooState here
    }
}
```

Now, I can't change FooState into an IObservable<int> because that would break other stuff that relies on Foo.

What I'd like to do is is declare an IObserver property on Bar that watches FooState.

Isn't this a basic use case?  How do I go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [BehaviorSubject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211949(v=vs.103)) to allow you to turn the property into both an observable stream and a property from which you can just read the latest value.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<int> _fooSubject = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
    public int FooState
    {
        get => _fooSubject.Value;
        set => _fooSubject.OnNext(value);
    }
    public IObservable<int> ObservableFooState => _fooSubject;
}
```

If the value of FooState is changing frequently then you'll probably want to use the [Sample](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Sample) operator prior to subscription. E.g.

```
//print out value every two seconds
foo.ObservableFooState
   .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) 
   .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Note that a common mistake is to use [Throttle](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Throttle) and then wonder why you hardly ever get any events!  (The reason is that Throttle resets the timeout every time a new event arrives so when the stream is updated frequently you'll never exceed the timeout value.)

Although it's old and slightly outdated in parts, I find [this guide](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html) to be very useful when trying to learn about Reactive.  The [Rx HOL](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/D/C5D669F9-01DF-4FAF-BBA9-29C096C462DB/Rx%20HOL%20.NET.pdf) is even older and even more outdated but still a very useful conceptual introduction - just don't take the code samples too literally.

If this class is actually a ViewModel, you might want to consider [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) but I would suggest steering away from that until you are really comfortable with Reactive.

Note that I haven't shown Dispose/Completion logic above.  You should consider when (if ever) you want to call OnCompleted on _fooSubject. Also bear in mind that [subscriptions are disposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323087/should-i-be-calling-dispose-on-reactive-extensions-rx-subjectt) and you probably want to ensure you dispose of them when your subscribers go out of scope.

Comment: thank you!  The class isn't a viewmodel, it's part of an in-memory cache of objects which are operated on by an external service.

Comment: Your original question was a little unclear over whether you truly required *no* changes to Foo.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: It does, since your answer retains the signature of Foo.  Many thanks.